# Android, to accept values from the user and to show them in next activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am supposed to ask the user for Name, Age, Email and phone number, and display the values in another activity. The example shown in Android Development training(from Google) did the same with one variable(key-value pair). However, here I have to pass 4 values. On looking up on how to do that, I came across Bundle. Using the same, the second activity does not show anything, ie the Activity is showing a blank screen, inspite of having 4 textView objects.
My codes go as follows:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME, message);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    message=editText2.getText().toString();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE, message);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    message=editText3.getText().toString();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL, message);
    EditText editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    message=editText4.getText().toString();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH, message);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**The second activity, DisplayMessageActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    String message=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME");
    String message1=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE");
    String message2=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL");
    String message3=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH");

    TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);

    TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(message1);
    TextView textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView3.setText(message2);
    TextView textView4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView4.setText(message3);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText7" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_ph"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_age"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_display_message.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. I am very new to programming in Android, so excuse me if I have made silly mistakes, and feel free to point out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passes wrongs keys in second Activity that's whys may your Activity crashes in `Oncreate()`.

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

Above you have declared keys for bundle but in second Activity you did mistake .

```
  Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    String message=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME");
    String message1=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE");
    String message2=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL");
    String message3=extras.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH");
```

you need to pass key like below line :

```
 String message=extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that in your `MainActivity` you declare **four variables** with all the **same value**. When you put the user input to your Bundle, it will always overwrite the value you inserted before, because there can only be **one individual key**. So you should edit your variables:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE_NAME";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE_AGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE_EMAIL";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE_PH";
```

The next problem lies in you `DisplayMessageActivity` class. You are trying to retrieve the data you inserted in your `MainActivity` with the **names of the variables** you declared in your `MainActivity`. Because of this, the `getString()` method returns `null`, as their is no key with the name of your variables.
You need to retrieve that data with the **value of the variables**. According to this, change your code to this:

```
String message=extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_NAME);
String message1=extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AGE);
String message2=extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_EMAIL);
String message3=extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE_PH);
```

As the variables in your `MainActivity` are **public static**, you can access them without the need for an instance of the `MainActivity` class.

So keep in mind, that you can access the saved data with the **value of the variable** and not **it's name**.

---

A tip from me: **Read some Java and Android tutorials, especially Java tutorials** ;)